# KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary access is denied

Tags: uwp

I am trying to implement the pictures sample in the  [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view#pictures-and-music-library-tree-view)

However I get an exception at

```
StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
```

The error is

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-managing-folders-in-the-music-pictures-and-videos-libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is also in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-managing-folders-in-the-music-pictures-and-videos-libraries)

Double click Package.appmanifest in solution explorer. Then go to the Capabilities Tab and check Pictures Library.